# Reliable factors

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

Briefly, my study ($n=188$) consists of using PCA on a 111-item questionnaire claiming to have 21 different disorders (factors). I did a MAP test (Velicer's Minimum Average Partial test) to decide on the number of factors to extract (it said 16), followed by PCA with varimax rotation. Using .4 as minimum loading. The tenth and eleventh components of the rotated component matrix have only 3 items (.698, .616, .542 and .572, .568, .483). Are these components reliable?

Comment: Your sample size is quite small given the number of dimensions you explore. Moreover, [tag:factor-analysis] would probably be better than PCA.

Comment: @chl is right about factor analysis, which tries to uncover latent factors (here disorders) in high-dimensional data. Are the factors interpretable? Well, look at them! Do they make sense?

Comment: The item contents definitely have a common theme, that is not my issue. My issue is whether factors with three items loading of the magnitude I report (.5-.6) are able to be classified as factors? @chl is quite right, my sample size is not ideal. As to PCA versus Common Factor model, that seems to be a hotly debated matter in the literature. Steiger (1979), and Stevens (2009) reckon it is much of a muchness. I really don't know either way but its too late now I have done PCA.

Comment: @Josh, You have to define specifically what is `reliable` and `able to be classified as factors`, for both phrases aren't clear at all.